# Fetch multiple Bond Yield curves in single Fetch from Bloomberg with XBBG

Tags: bloomberg, blpapi, bloom

I need to fetch multiple Bond Yield curves (1 month, 1 year, 5 year, etc) from different countries using Bloomberg API.

Searching for F476XXy Index at the terminal gives a list of generic tickers, like F47603M Index for the 3 month MXN Bond Yield.

Is there a generic way to reference all these Bonds and fetch it on a single blp.bdh (XBBG function) query or other pythonic way?

Comment: Do you want the actual bonds (and their yields) that make up the curve, or generic zero coupon rates (such as given by `F47610Y Index`)? Do you want just one value, or a time-series history?

Comment: I want the time-series history. I didnt understand the difference between the given Ticker and actual bonds. @DS_London

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the curve ticker from bloomberg.

1. Type CRVF and click on the curve you want. Ex. the MXN curve. I251
2. type GC I251 in your terminal which will plot the entire curve.

in the right hand side, under **plot curves** hover over the curve name and it'll have a ticker ID.

```
from xbbg import blp

data = blp.bds('YCGT0251 Index', 'CURVE_TENOR_RATES')
data
```

[image]

If you want the history

```
history = blp.bdh(data['tenor_ticker'], 'px_last', '2022-01-01','2023-09-20')
history
```

[image]